# Php/ajax return JSON in same form as javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, json, chart.js

I am using charts.js plugin to create charts. It is using a javascript array `data` to generate chart.

```
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        },
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
        }
    ]
};
```

I want to use ajax to return results for different range of time.
How can i generate a response with php so that when i read it in ajax success i can use it the same way i am using `var data`to generate initial chart.

```
        $.ajax('/chart.php', {
            type: 'POST',
            data: {range: range},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: How does the `data` in your `success()` function differ from the structure you've shown above?

Comment: It would just have different values in first array "labels" and sub arrays "data" will have the same number of values as "labels" first array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to create an array of objects, then use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and it should produce what you need. Try this:

```
$array = array();
$dataset = new stdClass;
$dataset->label = "My first dataset";
// repeat for each field
$array[] = $dataset;
echo json_encode($array);
```

What we can do to shorten this is rather than declare a new dataset each time we can [use an array and typecast it to an object](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting) like this:

```
$datasets = array();
$datasets[] = (object) array(
    'label' => "My First dataset",
    'fillColor' => "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
    'strokeColor' => "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    'pointColor' => "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    'pointStrokeColor' => "#fff",
    'pointHighlightFill' => "#fff",
    'pointHighlightStroke' => "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    'data' => [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
);
```

[Check out this eval.in](https://eval.in/371737) for a working example.

**Update**

For your complete structure you need:

```
$data = (object) [
    'labels' => ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets => []
];

$data->datasets[] = (object) [
    'label' => "My First dataset",
    'fillColor' => "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
    'strokeColor' => "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    'pointColor' => "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    'pointStrokeColor' => "#fff",
    'pointHighlightFill' => "#fff",
    'pointHighlightStroke' => "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    'data' => [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
];

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. What do i do with labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"], and how to put both "labels" array and multiple "datasets" in one array?